# Python: name of parent package not recognized in import statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, python-import

I understand that there are many questions on this topic, but most of the answers I've seen describe complex workarounds to problems that should, it seems to me, be simple. Here is my directory structure:

```
Mapper/
    LICENSE.txt
    README.txt
    setup.py
    bin/
        # nothing here, yet
    mapper/
        __init__.py
        process.py
        where.py
        # ...
        binconvert/
            __init__.py
            tocsv.py
            todict.py
            # ...
```

I would like to use absolute paths on all of my locally developed modules to decrease confusion and to avoid the bugs mentioned [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module.htm).

However, I am having multiple issues with this. When I run `process.py`, in which I `import` `tocsv.py` like so,

```
from mapper.binconvert import tocsv
```

I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mapper'`

I know I could have done `from binconvert import tocsv`, but like I said I am trying to have all my locally developed module imports use absolute paths.

I get the same error as before in `tocsv.py` when I am trying to import `where.py` like so:

```
 from mapper import where
```

For this one I believe there are ways to use the dot syntax relative `import`, but again, I would like to keep all my paths absolute. After all, I believe that according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) passage of python documentation, I should be able to do this:

> When packages are structured into subpackages (as with the sound package in the example), you can use absolute imports to refer to submodules of siblings packages. For example, if the module `sound.filters.vocoder` needs to use the echo module in the `sound.effects package`, it can use from `sound.effects import echo`.

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
     effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
              ...
     filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
              ...
```

Comment: If you are inside `process.py`, the `mapper` package is unknown, you would have to be outside of the `mapper` directory to import it. You cannot execute `process.py` as a script, the `from mapper.binconvert import tocsv` will only wotk if `mapper` is accessible from the current working directory where you Python script is executed. Beside `setup.py`, try `import mapper.process`, you will see it should work.

Comment: `from .binconvert import tocsv`. `mapper` is parrent directory of `process.py`, not in directory contains `process.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `process.py` you're already located inside the mapper package. Python will look through all the path defined in `sys.path` to find module, which in this case is only made of `["standard python path", "Mapper/mapper"]`.

In this case, python won't find a module named mapper inside those directories (you already are IN the mapper module).

Solutions for you :

1. Use the notation : `from .binconvert import tocsv` (conform to [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/))
2. Move up from 1 directory before start and launch `process.py` from the `Mapper` directory
3. Change the PYTHONPATH environment variable before launching `process.py` by adding the `Mapper`path

Comment: Shouldn't he add the 'Mapper' directory to the pythonpath so he can 'import mapper'?

Comment: @philippd yes of course, thank you, i corrected my mistake ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Regarding option two, would it work if I put `process.py` in the `bin` subdirectory of `Mapper`? I suppose since it is the "main script" it could belong there.

Comment: @VictorOdouard if you move `process.py`in the `bin` directory, you'll still need to change the pythonpath, to tell python to seek for the mapper module inside the `Mapper` directory

Comment: Ok, thank you Cédric. So to clarify, what determines what's in the sys.path is not where the module itself is located, but rather, where the script is executed from?

Comment: @VictorOdouard yes, that's it. sys.path is made by the standard path of python libraries, the current directory (where we are executed) and the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: Solution number one doesn't work in fact because of this : "Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "\_\_main\_\_", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports." In this case `process.py` is running as the main module.

Answer (score -1):

You can import being anywhere from "mapper" package, (using "from mapper.anything import that") if location of directory containing "mapper" package is in sys.path:

```
# in process.py
import os, sys
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #  "mapper" dir
MAPPER_ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(THIS_DIR) #  points to "Mapper" dir
if MAPPER_ROOT_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, MAPPER_ROOT_DIR)
```

You can include this snippet in every module the problem occurs. Convention is to set the path in first module that is being run (before importing any "own" package). sys.path contents is shared between all ran modules.

Comment: I do not think this is the correct way to solve the problem. Unless you do this for a quick test, but "You can include this snippet in every module the problem occurs", no.

Comment: "Can do" doesn't mean "Have to".